# Setting policy on a Steelhead Mobile Controller (SMC) for "Latency-based location awareness"

Tags: latency, wan-optimizer, riverbed

When setting policy on an SMC with reference to *Location Awareness - > Latency-based location awareness -> Optimize over adapters specified below if latency to SteelHead is more than: <#> ms*:

1. Should the time be tested w/ traceroute from the slowest location to
   the SMC?
2. If not, how should the threshold time in milliseconds be
   determined?

Right now, PCs with the SMC software installed are typically in locations where traceroute hops take >250ms to reach the SMC, yet the *Optimize over adapters specified below if latency to SteelHead is more than* setting is set to 10ms.

While this might not otherwise present a problem if it were possible to create a policy only optimizing wired adpaters using  *Adapters to Optimize*, the client PCs are often in an office w/ a Steelhead (and where pings and hops take >250ms to reach the SMC) but where creating a rule that would not apply to wireless adapters is impossible because the office lacks reliable wiring.

It therefore seems that the only current recourse is to change the *Optimize over adapters specified below if latency to SteelHead is more than* setting higher than the number of milliseconds it takes to reach the SMC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are confusing which part of the Steelhead infrastructure that setting refers to. The latency that is mentioned in that setting is between your client PC (with Steelhead mobile) and the local Steelhead, not the SMC. The idea is that with a latency under 10ms you have a high likelihood of being on the same branch location as the Steelhead, so it makes sense to activate the location-aware optimizing, and thus to offload optimization to the Steelhead rather than doing it alone on the client PC (it is also possible to combine both).

I think the default 10ms setting makes good sense on typical wired/wireless LANs, it may even be a little high in some environments.

Comment: OK, thank you very much. I will have to force the office to get wired.

Comment: @HanSoloMio I'm not sure I understand how wired/wireless fits into your problem here. Why would this not work over wireless?